# OSX Yosemite Crash - Can't Reopen App

Tags: macos, crash, adobe

I have a really annoying issue that happens when I am using Adobe Dreamweaver.

During saving when connected to a server and pushing files to it, it will often freeze.

The issue is, it locks up the app completely and I am forced to "Force Quit" the program.

However, once I force quit I cannot re-open that app again without restarting the mac.

You can see a video here of it happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBgQj_4fcIA

Something type of Cache or temp file is being cleared on restart and I would like to know if anyone knows of a way I can perform that same task through terminal?

It takes a lot of time out of my day when I have to relaunch all my tools sites etc each time it crashes. Since I use Dreamweaver all day and it crashes at least 5 times a day; its very annoying.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE** 
I am connected to a Windows Server that is mounted through an SMB server address. Any time it crashed, I make sure that the mount is still there and active which it is.

Here is the log in the 30 minute window it happened:

```
  2/4/15 3:04:46.912 PM firefox[607]: dnssd_clientstub handle_query_response: error reading result from daemon
2/4/15 3:05:24.813 PM CalendarAgent[367]: Stream 0x7f8fcd0382e0 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:05:51.003 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:05:51.027 PM Messages[617]: schema version 8009
2/4/15 3:05:51.685 PM identityservicesd[406]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f839a604280>: Configuring notification center for identifier: com.apple.iChat   topics: (
    "com.apple.madrid"
)
2/4/15 3:05:51.689 PM identityservicesd[406]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f839a604280>:    NC Disabled: NO
2/4/15 3:05:51.693 PM identityservicesd[406]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f839a604280>:   DND Enabled: NO
2/4/15 3:05:51.693 PM identityservicesd[406]: <IMMacNotificationCenterManager: 0x7f839a604280>: Updating enabled: YES   (Topics: (
    "com.apple.madrid"
))
2/4/15 3:05:51.718 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:05:51.732 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[56]: Session 100018 created
2/4/15 3:05:51.767 PM Messages[617]: [Warning] Calling cachedImageData from thread other than main thread.
(
    0   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff986536fb -[IMPerson(IMRenderingUtilities) cachedImageData] + 99
    1   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98652c4a -[Presentity customPicture] + 92
    2   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff986899a3 -[IMHandle(IMRenderingUtilities) monogramWithDiameter:style:blocking:] + 539
    3   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98650362 -[TranscriptImageResourceProtocol requestResourceData:fromURL:] + 9964
    4   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff9864db7b -[TranscriptImageResourceProtocol startLoading] + 140
    5   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95f62304 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader27_private_ScheduleOriginLoadEPK12NSURLRequestPK20_CFCachedURLResponse_block_invoke_2 + 61
    6   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a37b ___ZNK19URLConnectionLoader25withExistingProtocolAsyncEU13block_pointerFvP11URLProtocolE_block_invoke + 25
    7   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a33c _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 72
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98112274 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    9   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a1fd _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
    10  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a09e _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
    11  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e79ec0 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98146681 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9813880d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98137e3f __CFRunLoopRun + 927
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98137858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    16  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95efec80 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff990b390a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fd268 _pthread_body + 131
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fd1e5 _pthread_body + 0
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fb41d thread_start + 13
)
2/4/15 3:05:51.777 PM Messages[617]: [Warning] Calling imageDataBlocking from thread other than main thread.
(
    0   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98652dd3 -[IMPerson(IMRenderingUtilities) imageDataBlocking] + 99
    1   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98652cce -[Presentity customPicture] + 224
    2   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff986899a3 -[IMHandle(IMRenderingUtilities) monogramWithDiameter:style:blocking:] + 539
    3   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98650362 -[TranscriptImageResourceProtocol requestResourceData:fromURL:] + 9964
    4   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff9864db7b -[TranscriptImageResourceProtocol startLoading] + 140
    5   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95f62304 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader27_private_ScheduleOriginLoadEPK12NSURLRequestPK20_CFCachedURLResponse_block_invoke_2 + 61
    6   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a37b ___ZNK19URLConnectionLoader25withExistingProtocolAsyncEU13block_pointerFvP11URLProtocolE_block_invoke + 25
    7   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a33c _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 72
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98112274 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    9   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a1fd _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
    10  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a09e _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
    11  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e79ec0 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98146681 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9813880d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98137e3f __CFRunLoopRun + 927
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98137858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    16  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95efec80 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff990b390a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fd268 _pthread_body + 131
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fd1e5 _pthread_body + 0
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fb41d thread_start + 13
)
2/4/15 3:05:51.897 PM logind[72]: -[SessionManager getClient:withRole:inAuditSession:]:241: ERROR: No session dictionary for audit session 100018
2/4/15 3:05:51.897 PM logind[72]: _SMGetSessionAgent:73: ERROR: __SMGetClientForAuditSessionAgent failed 2
2/4/15 3:05:51.898 PM IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent[625]: SACShieldWindowShowing:925: ERROR: NULL response
2/4/15 3:05:52.005 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[56]: Killing auth hosts
2/4/15 3:05:52.005 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[56]: Session 100017 destroyed
2/4/15 3:05:52.098 PM NetAuthSysAgent[616]: NAHSelectionAcquireCredential The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.NetworkAuthenticationHelper error -1765328228 - acquire_kerberos failed chussey@248.144.91: -1765328228 - unable to reach any KDC in realm 248.144.91, tried 0 KDCs)
2/4/15 3:05:54.738 PM mds[35]: (Volume.Normal:2464) volume:0x7f96a7006600 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:1 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/wwwroot
2/4/15 3:05:57.332 PM WindowServer[133]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Finder" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
2/4/15 3:06:09.047 PM WindowServer[133]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Finder" after 12.72 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
2/4/15 3:06:09.113 PM identityservicesd[406]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7f839a5367b0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7f839a52b2d0> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
2/4/15 3:06:13.010 PM identityservicesd[406]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7f839a5367b0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7f839c91f9c0> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
2/4/15 3:06:18.637 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 1: Both of the following type_info's should have public visibility.  At least one of them is hidden. N5dvaui2ui8MessageTIKNS0_7UI_NodeEEE, N5dvaui8controls23UI_PictureSupplyMessageE.
2/4/15 3:06:19.459 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5dvaui2ui8MessageTINS0_7UI_NodeEEE, N5dvaui8controls23UI_ButtonChangedMessageE, N5dvaui8controls24UI_ControlChangedMessageE.
2/4/15 3:06:21.266 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5dvaui2ui8MessageTINS0_7UI_NodeEEE, N5dvaui8controls23UI_ButtonChangedMessageE, N5dvaui8controls24UI_ControlChangedMessageE.
2/4/15 3:06:21.843 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5dvaui2ui8MessageTINS0_7UI_NodeEEE, N5dvaui8controls23UI_ButtonChangedMessageE, N5dvaui8controls24UI_ControlChangedMessageE.
2/4/15 3:06:22.551 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:06:26.069 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve28UI_DVAClientWidgetEveAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.069 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve18UI_EvePopupAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.069 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve19UI_EveColumnAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.069 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve21UI_EveTextEditAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.069 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve16UI_EveRowAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.075 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve21UI_EveComboBoxAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.078 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve28UI_DVAClientWidgetEveAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:06:26.098 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 2: One or more of the following type_info's  has hidden visibility.  They should all have public visibility.   N5adobe23poly_copyable_interfaceE, N5adobe14implementation13poly_instanceINS_23poly_placeable_instanceIPN10dvaadameve16UI_EveRowAdapterEEEEE, N5adobe32poly_placeable_twopass_interfaceE.
2/4/15 3:07:47.580 PM WindowServer[133]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Dreamweaver" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
2/4/15 3:07:47.762 PM WindowServer[133]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Dreamweaver" after 1.18 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
2/4/15 3:08:30.772 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x60000010f9c0 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:13:14.399 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x6180001119d0 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:13:57.029 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 1: Both of the following type_info's should have public visibility.  At least one of them is hidden. N5dvaui2ui8MessageTIKNS0_7UI_NodeEEE, N5dvaui8controls23UI_PictureSupplyMessageE.
2/4/15 3:18:12.866 PM firefox[607]: dnssd_clientstub handle_query_response: error reading result from daemon
2/4/15 3:18:14.384 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x6180001152a0 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:18:25.768 PM com.apple.SecurityServer[56]: Session 100008 created
2/4/15 3:21:21.360 PM Dreamweaver[449]: dynamic_cast error 1: Both of the following type_info's should have public visibility.  At least one of them is hidden. N5dvaui2ui8MessageTIKNS0_7UI_NodeEEE, N5dvaui8controls23UI_PictureSupplyMessageE.
2/4/15 3:22:55.023 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:23:20.808 PM CalendarAgent[367]: Stream 0x7f8fcb639b20 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:23:25.808 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x610000110080 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:24:12.061 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.quicklook[665]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
2/4/15 3:24:29.413 PM Mail[454]: unlockFocus called too many times. Called on <NSSegmentedControl: 0x61800019a8f0>.
2/4/15 3:24:59.928 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x610000110860 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:25:01.713 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x608000112ab0 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:25:02.087 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:25:02.087 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:25:31.175 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:25:31.175 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:26:01.130 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:26:01.130 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:26:31.175 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:26:31.175 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:27:01.134 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:27:01.134 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:27:31.317 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:27:31.318 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:28:01.224 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:28:01.224 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:28:31.198 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:28:31.198 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:29:01.183 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:29:01.183 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:29:20.096 PM soagent[440]: Can't allocate SOHelper <SOMessageHelper: 0x7fd3894788e0> inside com.apple.soagent
2/4/15 3:29:31.319 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:29:31.319 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:29:33.790 PM soagent[440]: Can't allocate SOHelper <SOMessageHelper: 0x7fd389757c80> inside com.apple.soagent
2/4/15 3:29:38.493 PM identityservicesd[406]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7f839a5367b0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7f839c90cf00> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
2/4/15 3:29:48.767 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:29:48.787 PM com.apple.iCloudHelper[690]: objc[690]: Class FALogging is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyCircle.framework/Versions/A/FamilyCircle and /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FamilyNotification.framework/Versions/A/FamilyNotification. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2/4/15 3:29:48.797 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:29:56.003 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:29:59.599 PM Mail[454]: [WEB BUNDLE] Could not execute script: MUIWebDocumentDisplayController_sharedInstance.formatDocument(); error:TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'e.getBoundingClientRect()')
2/4/15 3:30:17.583 PM Microsoft Lync[451]: Could not find image named 'div bar 333'.
2/4/15 3:30:17.707 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.2 instead of 10.10.2. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
2/4/15 3:30:17.707 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x9334c7c7 ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 135
2/4/15 3:30:17.707 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9a88e130 _dispatch_client_callout + 50
2/4/15 3:30:17.707 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9a88e0b5 dispatch_once_f + 251
2/4/15 3:30:17.707 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x9a88f0d8 dispatch_once + 31
2/4/15 3:30:17.707 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x932dee88 _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 1050
2/4/15 3:30:17.708 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 5   CarbonCore                          0x932dea39 Gestalt + 150
2/4/15 3:30:17.708 PM Microsoft Alerts Daemon[696]: 6   Microsoft Alerts Daemon             0x0003f363 Microsoft Alerts Daemon + 17251
2/4/15 3:30:31.119 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessageNumberOfAttachments"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:30:31.119 PM Mail[454]: Unexpected flag key "MessagePriorityLevel"in flagsBySettingValueForKey
2/4/15 3:31:10.729 PM LUTool[699]: objc[699]: Class XByteCountFormatter is implemented in both /Library/PrivateFrameworks/SymAppKitAdditions.framework/Versions/B/SymAppKitAdditions and /Library/Application Support/Symantec/LiveUpdate/LUTool. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2/4/15 3:32:17.983 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.PubSub.Agent[712]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.pubsub.ipc
2/4/15 3:32:17.983 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.PubSub.Agent[712]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.pubsub.notification
2/4/15 3:32:41.570 PM Messages[617]: [Warning] Calling cachedImageData from thread other than main thread.
(
    0   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff986536fb -[IMPerson(IMRenderingUtilities) cachedImageData] + 99
    1   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98652c4a -[Presentity customPicture] + 92
    2   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff986899a3 -[IMHandle(IMRenderingUtilities) monogramWithDiameter:style:blocking:] + 539
    3   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff98650362 -[TranscriptImageResourceProtocol requestResourceData:fromURL:] + 9964
    4   IMRenderingFoundation               0x00007fff9864db7b -[TranscriptImageResourceProtocol startLoading] + 140
    5   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95f62304 ___ZN19URLConnectionLoader27_private_ScheduleOriginLoadEPK12NSURLRequestPK20_CFCachedURLResponse_block_invoke_2 + 61
    6   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a37b ___ZNK19URLConnectionLoader25withExistingProtocolAsyncEU13block_pointerFvP11URLProtocolE_block_invoke + 25
    7   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a33c _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 72
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98112274 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    9   CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a1fd _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 133
    10  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e7a09e _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
    11  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95e79ec0 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98146681 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9813880d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98137e3f __CFRunLoopRun + 927
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff98137858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    16  CFNetwork                           0x00007fff95efec80 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
    17  Foundation                          0x00007fff990b390a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fd268 _pthread_body + 131
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fd1e5 _pthread_body + 0
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff9c4fb41d thread_start + 13
)
2/4/15 3:33:14.554 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x618000110d70 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:33:16.169 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x600000312510 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:33:17.181 PM soagent[440]: Can't allocate SOHelper <SOMessageHelper: 0x7fd389496860> inside com.apple.soagent
2/4/15 3:33:24.942 PM identityservicesd[406]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7f839a5367b0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7f839ca18260> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
2/4/15 3:33:47.935 PM identityservicesd[406]: ApplePushService: <APSConnection: 0x7f839a5367b0> Received message from apsd: <APSIncomingMessage: 0x7f839c84e980> but it didn't match the enabled topics: (
) or opportunistic topics: (
)
2/4/15 3:33:57.379 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) The _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit key is not available on this platform.
2/4/15 3:34:25.550 PM soagent[440]: Can't allocate SOHelper <SOMessageHelper: 0x7fd38957e740> inside com.apple.soagent
2/4/15 3:34:30.635 PM soagent[440]: Can't allocate SOHelper <SOMessageHelper: 0x7fd3895607c0> inside com.apple.soagent
2/4/15 3:35:23.321 PM Mail[454]: Stream 0x60800010a710 is sending an event before being opened
2/4/15 3:35:39.686 PM Mail[454]: *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSWindow is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.
```

Comment: and saving locally works ? and you have the crash report for us to review?

Comment: Correct, works just fine. Even when I save and it does happen to freeze, the next time I restart and open it, it did save the local copy but locked up when pushing to the server.

Comment: any other aps freezing the working with server?

Comment: Only one I use that does it is Dreamweaver. I have uninstalled and reinstalled as well.

Comment: so we need to know more about your server and its connection. Also could ou look up in the Console (located in your Utility folder) and then look in the log at around the same time stamp as the event occurred. Then copy some of those lines in here.

Comment: Updated OP with server details and log

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's causing the crash, but there are certainly some cache files preventing it from restarting.

First of all, I'm going to guess that it is saving its application state (part of OS X Lion's Resume feature). To disable that, follow the instructions on [this link](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/01/turn-off-resume-per-app-in-mac-os-x-lion/).

Additionally, you may need to clear out a plist or two in your user library. [Here are the instructions](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/494811) on how to locate and remove the Dreamweaver preferences files (plists) which are most likely causing the crash.

Answer (score -3):

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin && sudo mv envvars _envvars
```

Works for me!

Comment: What does this actually do?

Comment: @patrix This is the quintessence of an accepted answer to this question: [Apache not starting on MAMP Pro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro). Maybe he hit the wrong question, or it's just blue spam or pink vandalism!